# Typora - Automatic Header At Top of Every A4 Page

Tags: header, markdown, footer

(Could not create a tag called typora because of insufficient reputation)

I have just started using Typora.io to write reports, and one thing that bugs me is the inability to have a header (footer) be generated automatically on top (at the bottom) of every new page. I am new to Markdown and all things related, so I do not even know how closely related Typora is to Markdown. Is there a way to automatically generate headers/ footers for Typora? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

File -> Export -> Export Settings -> PDF -> Header / Footer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).